# Inserting data in snowflake using Copy into from stage files

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bcp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My copy into command is as follows:

```
"COPY INTO "+ @[User::SchemaName] + "." + @[User::tableName] +  "  file_format = (field_delimiter = '|',null_if = ('NULL', 'null'),empty_field_as_null=false,validate_UTF8=false)"
```

After copying when I do select distinct on a column the output is as shown below.

Is there anything wrong with my copy into command? Or the flat file?

[image: 1,2,3 three empty records as distinct]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to examine your flat file. You have asked not to validate the utf8 data in your file format and also empty_field_as_null=false .

Examine your flat file to check if it is having any non utf8 characters and set the proper encoding.

you can use the file command on the flat file to see if it has any non utf values and based on that set the encoding.

example :
file ITEM_STACK.1
ITEM_STACK.1: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines

Review the table in the following documentation for the encoding values

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-summary-loading.html#supported-character-sets-for-delimited-files

Comment: "COPY INTO "+ @[User::SchemaName] + "." + @[User::tableName] +  "  file_format = (field_delimiter = '|',null_if = ('NULL', 'null'),TRIM_SPACE = TRUE,FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY =NONE,EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE,VALIDATE_UTF8 = TRUE )"

Comment: i changed the copy into but still i am getting that square box and when i do distinct all values are not distinct

Comment: CLUE REPORT NOT ORDERED.

Comment: CLUE REPORT NOT ORDERED.

Comment: those are repeatd